# How to combine nested array formulas in google sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

My dataset is as follows

[image]

*Tokens per week* is a static value, basically, it is hardcoded

*Stakes per week* is a sum of values in a column below. Eg. F2 contains formula: `=sum(F4:F)`

Values in calls below Week # are manually typed.

What I need is to calculate how many tokens each user has earned per week and show total amount in a row under *Tokens pending*

An example of Math for a very first row:

```
F4/F2*F1+G4/G2*G1
```

I have users constantly signing up for this campaign, so I need a formula to automatically apply for each new user.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. I put following formula in E4: `=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(A4:A), "", (SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(F4:BE4),ROW(F4:BE)),ROW(F4:BE),F4:BE)*($F$1/$F$2)-SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(BF4:BO4),ROW(BF4:BO)),ROW(BF4:BO),BF4:BO))))`

   But that gives me wrong results
2. I put following formula in E4 `=arrayformula(sum(iferror(F4:BE4/F$2:BE$2*F$1:BE$1,0)))`

   But that calculates it correctly for only one row. Formula is not automatically applied for each row below
3. I put following formula into E4: `=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(A4:A), "", arrayformula(sum(iferror(F4:BE/F$2:BE$2*F$1:BE$1,0)))))`

   But that gives me the wrong calculations again.

I am now considering to write user-defined function to handle this case.

I would appreciate any help!

**UPDATE 25-06-2020**

Here is a [link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MydpoygVAXh6Z3nqUWjKAgnbnlwt_DsvXM9nCBnoupM/edit#gid=0) as it was requested:

Comment: I recreate you dataset from the screenshoot and the second solution : `=arrayformula(sum(iferror(F4:BE4/F$2:BE$2*F$1:BE$1,0)))` ; work perfectly for me... can you show the incorrects values ?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @JulienMaret Yeap, it works, but it does not expand automatically to newly added rows. I have to apply that manually. And also, I have a typo, it should be "Formula is not automatically..."

Comment: @player0 added a link

Answer (score 1):

try in F2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F1:1="",,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(
 INDIRECT("F4:"&ROWS(A:A))*1), SIGN(F4:F)^0))))
```

and E4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IFERROR(F4:BE/F2:BE2*F1:BE1, 0), TRANSPOSE(SIGN(F1:BE1))^0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: it looks it works, but I have no idea what is going on there. Can you exapling your solution?